# Codeigniter URI Page redirects

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, controller, uri

I currently have an issue with my URI's

Example I have a function called `add` - users/add if there is an error with my input form it displays the errors on the users/add page but if all is good it goes back to the users page and shows a success but the uri remains /users/add and I have to re navigate to the users page.

**Update:**

**add:**

```
 $data['message'] = '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Thank You</strong> Your User Has Been Added</div>';
   $this->session->set_userdata('message', $data['message']);
   redirect(site_url('dashboard/users'));
```

**users:**

```
$message = $this->session->userdata('message');

        if($message === FALSE)
        {
            $message='';
        }else{
            $this->session->unset_userdata('message');
        }
```

**Original:**

**Controller:**

```
public function add()
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('userFirstName','First Name', 'required|trim|max_length[99]|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('userLastName','Last Name', 'required|trim|max_length[99]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userEmail','E-Mail', 'required|valid_email|trim|max_length[99]|xss_clean|is_unique[users.email]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('userPassword','Password', 'required|trim|max_length[99]|xss_clean');

            if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE)
                {
                    $userData = array(
                        'fName' => $this->input->post('userFirstName', TRUE),
                        'lName' => $this->input->post('userLastName', TRUE),
                        'email' => $this->input->post('userEmail', TRUE),
                        'password' => sha1($this->input->post('userPassword', TRUE))
                    );  

                    $this->db->escape($userData);
                    $this->user_model->addUser($userData);

                    $data['contentMangement'] = $this->options_model->systemOptions();
                    $data['pageTitle'] = 'Add User';
                    $data['message'] = '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Thank You</strong> Your User Has Been Added</div>';
                    $this->load->view('_assets/dashHeader', $data);
                    $this->load->view('dashboard/users', $data);
                    $this->load->view('_assets/footer');

                }elseif($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
                {
                    $data['contentMangement'] = $this->options_model->systemOptions();
                    $data['pageTitle'] = 'Add User';
                    $data['message'] = validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-error">', '</div>'); 
                    $this->load->view('_assets/dashHeader', $data);
                    $this->load->view('dashboard/addUser', $data);
                    $this->load->view('_assets/footer');
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you are not redirecting away from your current page. You are merely loading the 'users' view from `users/add`.

Think of it this way: The page you are at is `users/add`. What content this page shows is determined by which view(s) you load. So, even though you load the `user` view, you're still at the page `users/add`.

If you want to redirect, instead of

```
$this->load->view('dashboard/users',$data);
```

You need to do

```
redirect(site_url('users')); //or whatever your controller is called
```

However, in the latter case, you cannot pass data as you do when you load a view. If you want to retain data after a redirect, you will need to store it in session.

So, in your above code, where you create $data['message'], add it to the session:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('message',$data['message']);
```

When you redirect, at the other controller, retrieve the message, and remove it from session:

```
$message = $this->session->userdata('message');

if ($message === FALSE) {
   // message was not present in session
   $message = '';
} else {
    $this->session->unset_userdata('message');
}
```

**EDIT**

In your edit, in the `users` controller, you are extracting the message from session. But, it's not available to the view. You still need to pass it on.

```
$message = $this->session->userdata('message');

if($message === FALSE)
{
    $message='';
} else {
    $this->session->unset_userdata('message');
}

//at this point, message is only available to the controller
// lets send it to the view

$data['message'] = $message;
$this->load->view('yourView',$data);
```

Comment: you are an amazing help thanks,  I have updated my code as I am not getting the success into the view.

Comment: No problem at all. Glad to have helped. If my post answered your question, please don't forget to 'accept' it by clicking the check mark.

Comment: Could you look over my question update as I do not seem to be getting the message in my users view?